# Can't figure out linker error in VS2019 for friend in templated class

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++17, friend

Please note - StackOverflow found a dozen similar examples to this one.  I went through every one and still can't get my code to compile.  This may be similar to another question, but if you say it is - please make sure that the techniques shown in the example allow getting **this** code to compile.  Thanks in advance.

I'm playing around with some basic code trying to get better as a student of C++.  I'm sure this is a simple error/mistake, but I can't figure it out:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// General templated class
template <typename T>
class AddElements {
private:
    T lhs;
    T rhs;
public:
    AddElements(T lhs_init=T(), T rhs_init=T()): lhs{lhs_init}, rhs{rhs_init} { }
    T add() { return lhs + rhs; }

    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, const AddElements&);
};

template <typename T>
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& istr, const AddElements<T>& ae) {
    istr >> ae.lhs;
    istr >> ae.rhs;
    return istr;
}

int main() {
    std::size_t lines;
    std::string line_types;
    AddElements<int> mycol_ints;

    std::cin >> lines;
    std::cin >> mycol_ints;

    return 0;
}
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2019's C++ compiler:

```
$env:cl = "/EHsc /Wall /external:anglebrackets /external:W3 /external:templates- /experimental:external /RTCsu /sdl /analyze /std:c++17"

cl classtemplates.cpp
(...)
/out:classtemplates.exe
classtemplates.obj
classtemplates.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class std::basic_istream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __cdecl operator>>(class std::basic_istream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,class AddElements<int> const &)" (??5@YAAAV?$basic_istream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@AAV01@ABV?$AddElements@H@@@Z) referenced in function _main
classtemplates.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

Pointers to the fine manual welcome.  I've spent a while Googling around and looking at examples on cppreference.com but for now I'm stumped.

Comment: `template <typename T> std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, const AddElements<T>&);` -- You're trying to change the second parameter's internals, so it cannot be `const`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie You're right - that was one of the main problems.  However, I also had some of the syntax wrong.  songyuanyao shows the correct code options below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The friend declaration refers to a non-template operator, while the definition is a template operator, they don't match.

You might want

```
template <typename T>
class AddElements;
template <typename T>
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& istr, AddElements<T>& ae);

template <typename T>
class AddElements {
private:
    T lhs;
    T rhs;
public:
    AddElements(T lhs_init=T(), T rhs_init=T()): lhs{lhs_init}, rhs{rhs_init} { }
    T add() { return lhs + rhs; }

    friend std::istream& operator>> <>(std::istream&, AddElements&);
    //                              ^^
    // refer to the instantiation of the template operaotr>>
};

template <typename T>
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& istr, AddElements<T>& ae) {
    istr >> ae.lhs;
    istr >> ae.rhs;
    return istr;
}
```

Or you can make it non-template and define it inline in the class

```
template <typename T>
class AddElements {
private:
    T lhs;
    T rhs;
public:
    AddElements(T lhs_init=T(), T rhs_init=T()): lhs{lhs_init}, rhs{rhs_init} { }
    T add() { return lhs + rhs; }

    friend std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& istr, AddElements& ae) {
        istr >> ae.lhs;
        istr >> ae.rhs;
        return istr;
    }
};
```

BTW: The parameter `ae` should be declared as non-const; it's supposed to be modified in `operator>>`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it does not work for me.  Please see my revised question for what I get.

Comment: @JamesS. I think you should make the parameter `ae` as non-const.

Comment: That's it!  What a silly mistake on my part - all my problems are because I made the parameter const.  As soon as I remove the const from in front of AddElement the problem goes away.  I knew it had to be something simple.  Thanks again.